# How does wc -l `ls` give the actual number of lines?

Tags: shell, ls, command-substitution

Can anyone explain to me how does this command work.

```
wc -l `ls`
```

while this command gives the total number of java lines or txt lines.

Comment: Try putting echo in front, then you'll see what the command really looks like. `echo wc -l \`ls\``

Answer (score 2):

`ls` outputs a list of file/directory names in the current directory.

`ls` will be replaced by the output of `ls`.  So you're actually running something like:

```
wc -l file1 file2 file3 ... fileN
```

And of course `wc` will open each file named in the command line in turn, to count the lines.

The same effect could be had by running:

```
wc -l *
```

Note that this only holds if none of the file names in the current directory contain any “weird” character (whitespace or `\[?*`).

Comment: If \`ls\` were replaced by the output of `ls`, then `wc` would be asked to count the lines of **one** file whose (long and multi-line) name is the output of `ls`. \`ls\` expands to the output of `ls` minus the trailing newline characters, and is then split into several words (by default on spc, tab and newline characters) and then each word is subject to globbing. It is only equivalent to `wc -l *` is the special case where no file name in the current directory contain spc, tab, newline, `*`, `?` or `[` characters. Using `ls` that way is just plain wrong.

Comment: I could have been more specific; but yes the shell will split the output from `ls` into tokens, based on IFS.  etc.  Regardless, as you say, using `ls` like this is weird at best, and dangerous at worst.

Comment: The note should go above the `*` as `*` is not affected by whitespace or special characters. With the exception of files starting with `-`, which may be interpreted by wc as an option. workaround `wc -l -- *`

Comment: See also http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#ls on this "Useless (and Sometimes Dangerous) Use of `ls`"